Ubuntu24.04 cudaGetDevice Failed
My program Like this:
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>

int main() {
  int id = -1;
  int state = cudaGetDevice(&id);
  if (state != cudaSuccess) std::cout << "Failed!";
  return 0;
}

My output is Failed!
I try to some ways like this question:
cudagetdevice-failed-status-cuda-driver-version-is-insufficient-for-cuda-run
However it does not work.
My nvcc version is:
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2024 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Oct_29_23:50:19_PDT_2024
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.6, V12.6.85
Build cuda_12.6.r12.6/compiler.35059454_0

My cuda driver version is:
⋊> /u/l/c/bin nvidia-smi                                                                                                                                                                                                                       (base) 23:20:24
Mon Dec  2 23:20:47 2024       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 560.35.03              Driver Version: 560.35.03      CUDA Version: 12.6     |
|-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id          Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |           Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                        |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+========================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Ti     Off |   00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   41C    P8             16W /  225W |      83MiB /   8192MiB |     41%      Default |
|                                         |                        |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                              |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                              GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                               Usage      |
|=========================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      2908      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                             69MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Update:
I use std::cout << cudaGetErrorString(state) << std::endl;
And the output is 'out of memory`

try: cudaError_t err = cudaGetDevice(&id); std::cout << cudaGetErrorString(err) << std::endl;  And report back whatever is printed out from that.

Thanks I try you way, and the output is out of memory @RobertCrovella

If that were my machine, I would reboot and try again.

I reboot my machine, but still have this problem, I do not know why. Thanks! @RobertCrovella

Thanks! I successfully solved the problem by cold reboot my machine. However, performing a warm restart on my machine did not resolve the issue. @RobertCrovella

I successfully solved the problem by this way:

you should uninstall the old nvidia-driver:

sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*


Install new nvidia-driver:

sudo apt update

sudo apt search '^nvidia*' 

And then install the nvidia-driver,which you need
3. Install the cuda-toolkit, rember the cuda-toolkit version should the same as your nvidia-driver cuda version
After you install your cuda-toolkit, you must cold reboot your machine(not warm reboot machine)
